# Mysql : How to update a table field to a value fetched from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table let's name **A and B** having following field :

**TABLE A**

```
| ID | COUNTRY_CODE | COUNTRY_NAME | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
```

**TABLE B**

```
| ID | COUNTRY_CODE | COUNTRY_NAME |
```

Now I need to update **country_code** field from **Table A** whose value is to be fetched from **Table B**.

The pseudo-code is something like this :

```
for all rows in Table A :
  set A.country_code = (select B.country_code from B where B.country_name = A.country_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use update with `JOIN`

```
update TableA A
inner join tableB B on B.country_name = A.country_name
set A.country_code=B.Country_code
```

Answer (score 0):

No need `join`, just try sql as below:

```
update TableA set country_code = B.country_code from TableB B where A.country_name = B.country_name
```

Comment: not a valid mysql syntax

Comment: Yep..I just tried this in Mysql, it failed. But it will work in a PostgreSQL update. @fa06